# Google API cannot create new project

Tags: google-api

I am trying to create a new project with Google API, but when in the wizard I select 'create a new project', and I click next nothing happens.

I attach a screenshot from the website.

Comment: Same issue here! Must be something about Google. Tried 3 different accounts and got the same result!